# How to run dependent samplers with load distribution in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, stormrunner-load

I am looking to run a service mix of 3 APIs with different loads sequentially. Q1 - 20%, Q2 -10%, Q3 - 70%
However, Q1 in independent and Q2 is dependent on variable generated in Q3.

I have following setup. I cannot have multiple thread groups and need transaction controllers as I need to upload this to Storm Runner.

```
ThreadGroup - Threads 10,  Loop 1
 --- Q1ThroughPutController -20%
    ---Q1TransactionController
 --- Q2ThroughPutController - 10%
    ---Q2TransactionController 
 --- Q3ThroughPutController - 70%
    ---Q3TransactionController
```

Current run looks like this:

Q3 - Fail
Q3 - Fail
Q3 - Fail
Q3 - Fail
Q1 - Fail
Q3 - Fail
Q1 - Pass
Q3 - Pass
Q2 - Pass
Q3 - Pass

Answer (score 0):

According to [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

Your setup assumes that:

- 20% of users are executing Q1
- 10% of users are executing Q2
- 70% of users are executing Q3

so there is no way for user who ran Q3 to switch to Q1

You need to amend your correlation logic to use **properties** instead of variables, properties are global so they will be accessible to all threads, you will have to do some custom Groovy scripting using suitable [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Alternative solution would be using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) to pass your variables between different threads and also implement some blocking logic so the virtual user will "wait" for the variable value before proceeding

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue here is not variable scope.  The problem is when Q3 is initiated in first four, the variable is not created as it is created in Q2 and as you can see Q3 after Q2 has passed.
 I am looking for a way to execute Q3 only after Q2 or give priority to Q2 somehow